# Can i test if a link requires confirm in a capybara feature spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

Is there a way to test if a link or button requires the user to confirm in a feature spec?

I´m looking for a solution that does not require selenium.

I know it should be possible to test if there is a data-confirm attribute but is there a more streamlined way to do it that is less linked to the implimentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For capybara

```
 page.driver.browser.accept_js_confirms  
 page.driver.dismiss_js_confirms!
```

There are more please check

https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit